# Pinax on MediaTemple/other hosting company

Tags: django, pinax

I wanted to deloy a pinax project on a mediatemple. Does anyone know how to go about making it work there? or any other webhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some instructions for how to install on WebFaction:

- [How do I install pinax](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?pid=9471) (scroll down to seanf's post)
- [Pinax setup on Webfaction](http://audreyr.posterous.com/pinax-setup-on-webfaction-part-2)

Comment: I'll try to follow the steps tomorrow. Thanks